# Facebook logout/disconnect FB.login() called when user is already connected

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, authorization, logout

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'appID',
            status     : true,
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>
      <div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Every time when i click on [Login with Facebook] button i see in `JS Console` this message "FB.login() called when user is already connected."

How to disconnect user?

Answer (score 13):

Use FB.getLoginStatus method to find whether the user in logged in or not.

If they already logged in, try to hide the Login button. Because the login button will be visible always and do nothing on click when the user already logged in.

Refer this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) for FB.getLoginStatus

Answer (score 5):

Good answer from Abirami, one additional item.

> How to disconnect user?

Disconnecting a user is done with a call similar to FB.login() called FB.logout() See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Comment: FB.logout() will logout user from other tab in which he is logged in with facebook too

Answer (score -3):

This IS the solution that no one is telling anyone because it highlights a Facebook bug so be prepared for me to get voted down...

FB.login() will get called after any user tries to logout if the 'autologoutlink' parameter on the Javascript facebook button is set to true.

The problem is this:

```
    <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

(((autologoutlink="true")))

When true is set the login button is always called after the user logs out (FB.login) and you have set your window.location to some other page which gets redirected back to the login page, FB.login it is treated like an object, much like an app developer is.

On a console you will see that FB.login() always gets called after the user logs out because of this 'autologoutlink' parameter on the Javascript facebook login button bug.

I now fear for the moron that voted me down lol...

YES this is a bug with the javascipt SDK asynchronously all.js script

The secret would be to load the javascript Facebook button without the autologoutlink="true" parameter but use the php sdk to load the logout button afterwards.

Something like this in php to put a javascript sdk login button but then post a php logout button to get around the asynchronous bug in the Facebook code:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$logoutUrl=null;
$login_page='replace this for logged in page redirect'; //http://domain.com/loggedin
$logout_page='replace this for logged out page redirect'; //http://domain.com/loggedout

If ($user){
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array(
  'next'=>$logout_page
  ));
  $fb_login='<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'">Logout</a>';
}else{
  $fb_login='<fb:login-button width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>';
}
```

Use the javascript SDK and

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  window.location='$login_page';
});
```

and somewhere on your page

```
echo $fb_login;
```

So you use the Javascript login and the php logout redirect methods and it will patch the bug on the Javascript login button autologoutlink="true" parameter which we will not use, you will just need a logout button image and css and FB.login() will not get called anymore after FB.logout() each time.

You can see how to shorten this a whole bunch I'm sure but this is the fix that no one wants to tell you for looking.

And now for my Pointless Rant...

In short, if they run a totally unsecure session in the PHP SDK and they can not even make a button work then don't look to them for answers!.

You are forced to use what Facebook are defining as asynchronous scripts however they are only one sided security, anyone can spoof a domain or hijack an unsecure session where all payments are handled by said spoofed domain ergo any app  on Facebook is totally and utterly hackable and they know it, they just haven't figured out a way to shovel you their BS apart from the word asynchronous which is NOT two way security is it.

Try design anything that is hooked using an asynchronous JAVASCRIPT and then make is secure, they can always blame YOU for the fact they can not deliver a button that says the user is or is not connected in any simple terms with today's scripting and technology.

I'm laughing right now.

I guess that's why we are on stackoverflow...

Personally I think the Facebook javascript and php SDk should be simple and not force the designer to learn their own insane methods in social design but simply provide a method that says YES the user is logged in so... or NO the user isn't so... but Facebook seem to think they are adobe and con-volute everything with kak leaving us to read a four story building of books on their personal philosophy of design to only be left with no examples and code that you would have to be psychic to debug for which will only be changed two days after you finish building your app which took fourteen years just because they fail to deliver and instead like to sound like they know what they are doing to cover so many revisions that are made to remove said bugs.

Like adobe, if it worked, we wouldn't have to do a course in it's design would we ?

But as it is shite and wastes billions of hours of human resources then I'm sure at some point you will be forced to pay for a qualification in it because that means more money right ?.

I mean you have to pass all payments through Facebook already in such a way that they can remotely edit your sessions ergo your app ergo your database ergo your payments.

What TF has your payments got to do with Facebook when what you deliver is what they should be paying you for and ultimately brings, keeps and delivers them more users.

Same with Hollywood, they call piracy a free film on the internet instead of paying you for the free advertising of their products while Hollywood take 80 billion and hour in interest, ban interest!.

Piracy is making money from others work not slavery and to be sued for it or actually pay for doing it.

Remember this lecture it will do you well.

I said to much LOL...

When it is all clear you will see just where the road is taking us.